# Do I owe state taxes for a temporary (4 month) residence in California?

Tags: united-states, taxes, california, state-income-tax

During 2012, I spent the first 4 months living in California while in a startup accelerator program.  I had a California apartment lease with my name on it during that time.  I earned income during this time.

It was not my permanent residence; I still maintained and paid rent on my permanent residence in Michigan.

Do I need to file tax documents with the state of California for this period?  What are the rules for answering that question?

Answer (score 5):

Actually you're *part*-resident, not *non*-resident. Its the same form in California ([540NR](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2012/540nr_table_of_contents.shtml)), but the difference is significant. California taxes its residents on **worldwide** income. So for the time you were a California resident - **all** of your income is taxed by California. For all the rest of the time - only the income derived from California.

You can get more details on [this FTB site](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/individuals/faq/ivr/209.shtml).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since you have California income. You file as a California nonresident.